# java page filter problems

Tags: java, spring-tool-suite

```
@GetMapping("/filter/{talla}/{tipo}/{marca}/{palabra}")
    public String busqueda(Model model,
                           @PathVariable(name = "talla", required = false) String talla,
                           @PathVariable(name = "tipo", required = false) String tipo,
                           @PathVariable(name = "marca", required = false) String marca,
                           @PathVariable(name = "palabra", required = false) String palabra) {

        List<Zapatilla> zapatillas = servi.todasZapatillas();

        // Verificar si algún parámetro tiene un valor y aplicar el filtro correspondiente
        if (talla != null) {
            zapatillas = servi.filtrarPorTalla(zapatillas, talla);
        }

        if (tipo != null) {
            zapatillas = servi.filtrarPorTipo(zapatillas, tipo);
        }

        if (marca != null) {
            zapatillas = servi.filtrarPorMarca(zapatillas, marca);
        }

        if (palabra != null) {
            zapatillas = servi.buscarPorNombre(zapatillas, palabra);
        }
        
        model.addAttribute("zapatillas", zapatillas);
        return "shoes.jsp";
    }
```

in theory this has to work with each filter but only works if i put every single one otherwise it give me a 404 error and i dont know why

i tried solving it with changing estructure checking routes but nothing works

Comment: Hint: Let's say you want to filter by palabra and _only_ palabra ... what would your path look like for your GET call? You may want to consider changing your path variables to query parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter data then user Query param instead of path variable.

```
@GetMapping("/filter")
    public String busqueda(Model model,
           @RequestParam(name = "talla", required = false) String talla,
           @RequestParam(name = "tipo", required = false) String tipo,
           @RequestParam(name = "marca", required = false) String marca,
```

Something like this.

Your api will be : `http://localhost:8080/filter?talla=somevalue&tipo=somevalue`

You can add all the values or skip whatever not present.